# Managing navigation controllers / view controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Not sure how to title this question, but i'v got such a problem: Up until now i my app runs mainly in one navigationcontroller with table views. But now i'm trying to integrate dropdown settings menu, and can't get it properly done.

The way i'v done now and it works

The changeController is called from one button. ChangeController is in appdelegate.

```
- (void) ChangeController
{
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    DropDownExample *e = [[DropDownExample alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:e];
    [e release];
    [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

But this approach has consequances - there is no transition if button is pressed, the settings menu appears instantly, you cannot go back via navigation bar above (nothing there).

So how to do this properly?? I'm new to ios, so just tell me the whole idea how to do this.

Didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method from appdelegate

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease

];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    TableViewController *tableVC = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableView" bundle:nil andType:CONTROLLER_TYPE_FIRST];
    UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableVC];
    self.navigationController = navC;
    [tableVC release];
    [navC release];
     self.window.rootViewController = _navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to insert new Controller on navigation stack or start with a different navigation controller?

Comment: Hmm, don't know honestly.. I just wish the transition between them appears as usual, and i have a ability to go back to the view from which it was called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's the answer. Write the method `changeController` in the same class where the Button exists which calls `changeController`

In the method, write this.

```
- (void) ChangeController
{
    DropDownExample *e = [[DropDownExample alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:e animated:YES];
    [e release];
}
```

What you want is to insert new UIViewController on the top of the present Stack. If you would be having a navigation Bar at the top by default then there would be a back Btn by default, which would pop up that controller.

Comment: But how do i access navigationController that way to pushViewController?

Comment: `self.navigationController` gives access to navigation controller. Btw, post your appDidFinishLaunching method from AppDelegate.

Comment: added method you asked. self.navigationController gives property not found in ButtonClass. Sorry if these are basics, i'm only 5 days in objective-c and ios programming. It's kinda different from Java which i'm used to.

Comment: Where do you call `changeController` method? I guess you are doing it in the Button class.

Comment: Yes i do call it from button class after the button is pressed like this >>      AppDelegate *newControll = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [newControll ChangeController];

Comment: Got it working at last, by accessing like this newControll.navigationController. Thank you very much for your help !